# how to use adb and meteor at the same time

Tags: android, meteor, adb

It seems that Meteor CLI doesn't play nice with ADB.

After using ADB commands, for example `adb logcat`, running `meteor run android-device` meteor doesn't find the connected android device:

`ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to install apk to device: ERROR: Failed to deploy to device, no devices found.`

If I then try `adb devices` to see if the device is connected I get:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

Only completely killing all processes associated with the port I can get `adb devices` to work, but even then when I see my device, meteor still cannot find it.

Another method I devised is to start only the server using meteor and use `adb install` to install the built android debug apk. However while running the app this way it seems that it doesn't always refresh upon code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are two adb servers that conflict with each other. Either use Meteor's adb or make meteor use your existing adb:

Use `USE_GLOBAL_ADK=t meteor run..` to start your app instead of `meteor run..` to run your app. This would require your `ANDROID_SDK` env variable to be set too which is usually done by your previous installation.

Comment: How does one use Meteor's adb? logcat for example.

Comment: @Uri I'm assuming it uses a different binary to run the adb server. The SDK can be found at `~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk`

Comment: Cool. Specifically `~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat`

Comment: It seems that since 1.2 this is no longer a problem.